# Disable Snap To Edge Feature in Gnome 2

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome

Is there a way to disable the snap-to-edge feature in Gnome 2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I'm pretty happy with Gnome so far, but I don't have a big monitor and I'd really like to be able to move my windows off the edge of the screen without resistance.

I'm not sure if its called snap-to-edge or magnetic edges, but in either case, I'd like to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is changeable directly in CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) under Window Snapping.

However, if you are using Metacity like most stability-lovers do (and if you didn't install Compiz you probably are), you can't do it in a setting but you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging.

Comment: I was hoping that there was some way that I could disable it permanently, but `Shift`+drag will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure someone can give a more direct answer, as I dont have my Linux machines available to me at the moment.

I believe it is a setting in Compiz,  You can look for it there in the CSSM.  If you cant find it, you can enable "wobbly windows" which will ask you to disable snapping.  At that point you can disable "wobbly windows" again if you want.

Comment: but the method a mentioned will disable window snapping